# How to get YouTube video title as URL?

Tags: youtube, google-talk

I want to set my gtalk status to a youtube video link. But the link doesn't show title, and shows actual URL. I want it to show the title clicking on which people go to the video page.

What is the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't parse HTML's in status message. So, No. It's not possible.

Comment: Whilst I agree that it's probably not possible, the fact that it doesn't parse HTML is not necessarily the reason.

Comment: Explain why you think so.

Comment: Google could provide an alternative syntax for embedding this information, rather than (a subset of) HTML. Gtalk is not primarily browser based and there are better (more friendly) solutions for simple markup. Gtalk does currently offer some alternative markup (which can be used in the status), such as `*bold*`, `-strikethrough-` and `_italic_`, but even these simple formatting markers aren't compatible with all gtalk clients.

Comment: True. But ultimately, they are all parsed into HTML. What you're talking about is purely guesswork, of something that *might* happen sometime in future. I have no reason to consider that. Anyway, point taken. Thanks for your view.

Comment: What if I'm using Pidgin? Will it work then? Will my friends on gtalk be able to see it?

Comment: No. I think it'll show up as `Text <http://example.com>` like this. But not as hyperlinked.